# Why BiPredicate evaluates the two boolean conditions prior to applying the test function

Tags: java, predicate

Consider this sample code:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    SomeObj obj = null;
    if (obj == null || obj.getSomeMethod() == null) {
        System.out.println("Obj is null");
    }

    if (result((x, y) -> x == null || y == null, obj, obj.getSomeMethod())) {
        System.out.println("Obj is null");
    }
}

private static <X, Y> boolean result(final BiPredicate<X, Y> p, final X argX, final Y argY){
    return p.test(argX, argY);
}
```

In the first If condition I get the message "obj is null" but in the second If condition I get a NullPointerException.
This BiPredicate should't be a short circuit operator (if the first condition is true don't bother evaluating the second one)?

Comment: First one is short-circuiting. It doesn't evaluate the right-hand side expression if the left-hand side is false. Second one evaluates all expressions, including `obj.getSomeMethod()`, which NullPointers if obj = null

Answer (score 4):

No, you're passing three arguments to `result`:

- The `BiPredicate`
- `X`
- `Y`

They get evaluated before calling `result`, which means the `BiPredicate` is evaluated and returns a `BiPredicate` (which is not executed), then `X` is evaluated, than `Y` but `Y` is `obj.getSomeMethod()` and `obj` is null, so the `NullPointerException` is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

This actually has nothing to do with `BiPredicate` per se.

```
if (result((x, y) -> x == null || y == null, obj, obj.getSomeMethod())) {
```

is just invoking a method, in exactly the same way that

```
if (someMethod("Hello", obj, obj.getSomeMethod())) {
```

does: Java evaluates all of the arguments, and then passes them to the method.

So, it evaluates `obj.someMethod()`, whether or not `obj` is `null`. If it is `null`, you will get a `NullPointerException` here.

`BiPredicate` has no special support in the language: it's just a regular library-defined interface. You don't get any special lazy evaluation by using it.